# Mysql how to combine GROUP BY and COUNT here

Tags: mysql, sql

This must be quite easy, but I cannot find a good solution myself.
I have two tables:

```
file
+----+--------+
| id | system |
+----+--------+
|  1 |     AA |     
|  2 |     AA |     
|  3 |     BB |     
|  4 |     AA |     
+----+--------+     

feature
+----+---------+------+
| id | file_id | name |
+----+---------+------+
|  1 |       1 |    A |
|  1 |       2 |    A |
|  1 |       2 |    B |
|  1 |       3 |    B |
|  1 |       3 |    C |
|  1 |       4 |    A |
|  1 |       4 |    B |
|  1 |       4 |    C |
+----+---------+------+
```

and I want to count how many times a feature was added to files with a specific system. For that, I have the following query:

```
SELECT f.name, COUNT(*) AS nr
FROM dossier d
JOIN feature f
ON f.file_id = d.id
WHERE d.system = 'AA'
AND d.id NOT IN (3157,3168,3192)
GROUP BY f.name
```

which gives the desired output:

```
+------+----+
| name | nr |
+------+----+
|    A |  3 |
|    B |  2 |
|    C |  1 |
+------+----+
```

Now I also want to know the total amount of files with the same specific system. A simple separate query would be:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM file WHERE system = 'AA' AND id NOT IN (3157,3168,3192)
```

I've added the extra `AND id NOT IN` (which is irrelevant for this example) just to show that the actual query is much more complex. If I use a separate query to get the total I would have to duplicate that complexity, so I want to avoid that by returning the total from the same query.

So how can I count the number of files in the first query?

Desired output:

```
+------+----+-------+
| name | nr | total |
+------+----+-------+
|    A |  3 |     3 |
|    B |  2 |     3 |
|    C |  1 |     3 |
+------+----+-------+
```

Comment: Your second query does a count on all items (not following the overall GROUPING applied to first query). So either keep them as 2 seperate queries, or insert the second into the first as a subquey.

Comment: What's this? `NOT IN (3157,3168,3192)`

Comment: Since MySQL doesn't support windowed functions currently, I think that you're going to be stuck duplicating your logic, such as with @MotoGP's solutions.

Comment: @JSantos, just showing that IRL some files have to be excluded from the result based on other criteria. Like I said, the actual queries are much more complex, that's why I was looking for a way to combine these queries.

Comment: @TomH, bummer I hoped to avoid two full blown queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way using `Sub-query`

```
SELECT f.NAME,
       Count(*) AS nr,
       (SELECT Count(*)
        FROM   FILE
        WHERE  system = 'AA'
               AND id NOT IN ( 3157, 3168, 3192 )) as Total
FROM   dossier d
       JOIN feature f
         ON f.file_id = d.id
WHERE  d.system = 'AA'
       AND d.id NOT IN ( 3157, 3168, 3192 )
GROUP  BY f.NAME
```

Or Use `CROSS JOIN`

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT f.NAME,
               Count(*) AS nr,
        FROM   dossier d
               JOIN feature f
                 ON f.file_id = d.id
        WHERE  d.system = 'AA'
               AND d.id NOT IN ( 3157, 3168, 3192 )
        GROUP  BY f.NAME) A
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT Count(*) AS Total
                   FROM   FILE
                   WHERE  system = 'AA'
                          AND id NOT IN ( 3157, 3168, 3192 )) B
```